# Find the Expected value of a Random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Assume random variable $$X \sim f_X(x) \,\,\, -2 \leq x\leq 2$$

Now Assume we need to compute the following

$$F= \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{1+(G(X))^2}\right)$$
where we define the function
$$G(x) = \mathbb{1}(|x|\le c) = \begin{cases} 1, & -c \le x \le c \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

with $c<2$...

Can I say that the following is correct

$$F = \int_{-2}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+(G(x))^2}\right) f_X(x)\, dx =\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-c}^{c} f_X(x)\, dx+ \int_{-2}^{-c} f_X(x)\,dx\,+\int_{c}^{2} f_X(x)\,dx$$

Comment: It is true in your case that for any measurable function $g$, $\mathbb{E}[h(X)] = \int_{-2}^2 h(x) f_X(x) dx.$ This is not what you have written; your limits of integration are $-c$ to $c$, and you stipulate $|c| < 2$. In this case the function $h = 1/G(x)^2$ is not defined on $[-2,-c) \cup (c, 2]$, hence $h(X)$ is not even defined.

Comment: @snarski, sorry i meant to say that $c<2$....

Comment: you must make this definition for the whole function not for $G$. Else your function $1/G(x)^2$ will be infinite whenever $G$ is $0$. your expectation is still defined on $[-2,2]$ and in this range, your random function still takes infinite values..

Comment: thank you, do you mean that the limits of the integral are the only wrong thing i have above? @SeyhmusGüngören... if yes how can I find them?

Comment: @Henry yes it is wrong. The limits are $[-2,2]$ but your integral blow up because it will become $\infty$ for some interval $[c,2]$ and [-2,-c]. Therefore you cannot integrate this function.

Comment: Oh you are right, please can you check if it OK now, i have edited the question...@SeyhmusGüngören

Comment: the other integrals will be from $[-2,-c]$ and $[c,2]$

Comment: thank you for your help, i think i have it correct now @SeyhmusGüngören

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören can you verify if the above is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can varify that $F$ is correctly calculated based on given definitions in the question. It can however be furher simplified as:

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-c}^{c} f_X(x)\, dx+ \int_{-2}^{-c} f_X(x)\,dx\,+\int_{c}^{2} f_X(x)\,dx=1-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-c}^{c} f_X(x)\, dx$$

Comment: thanks how come is that possible?

Comment: $\int f_X(x)dx=1$

Comment: yes but $\int_{-2}^{-c} f_x(x)dx + \int_{c}^{2} f_x(x)dx \neq \int f_X(x) $?

Comment: yes but $\int=\int_{-2,-c}+\int_{c,2}+\int_{-c,c}$